# Exif Encoding in Windows Explorer

Tags: encoding, exif

Applying any modifications to XIF data in our code produces encoding issues in Windows Explorer. Here the property FileExplorerTitle is modified and the resulting character set is changed to some double-byte encoding.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVzMpvo-XPg&feature=plcp&context=C3c03effUDOEgsToPDskKa3ZJh-GhqCGE6M_pXkrQw

Comment: Can you please put the relevant code here, inside StackOverflow for us? It makes it much easier for us to help you. Thanks for the video though.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file and applying attributes:                                                  Dim oXIFmedia As New ImageExifData(sFileName)
oXIFmedia.FileExplorerTitle = Title

Code inside ImageExifData.cs:

```
public enum ExifDataTypes : short
{
        UnsignedByte = 1,
        AsciiString = 2
}

public string FileExplorerTitle
{
        set
        {
            try
            {
                this.SetPropertyString(40091, value);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
}



public void SetPropertyString(Int32 PID, string Value)
{
        byte[] Data = this._Encoding.GetBytes(Value + "\0");
        SetProperty(PID, Data, ExifDataTypes.AsciiString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WindowsTitle` EXIF field is encoded with Unicode. Try:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value);
```